# Java: How to Convert type Instant to type XMLGregorianCalendar?

Tags: java

Code:

```
private static Instant now;
now = new Instant();
```

How do I convert the variable now to type XMLGregorianCalendar? I've been doing research on it and I'm quite confused. I have found no similar questions, and so anything will be useful.

Note:
I am using Java 6.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you need an `XMLGregorianCalendar` object? The new Java 8 date and time classes already have support for the ISO 8601 date format, if you're doing this because you need to format or parse a date and time in ISO 8601 format (which is the standard format for dates and times used in XML).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();

GregorianCalendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
cal1.setTimeInMillis(now.toEpochMilli());

XMLGregorianCalendar cal2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal1);
```

If you are doing this just because you want to format an `Instant` to a `String` in ISO 8601 format, then there is an easier way:

```
String dateTime = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(now);
```

*edit* - for the Joda Time class `Instant`, do `now.getMillis()` instead of `now.toEpochMilli()`.

Comment: I am using the Instant class from org.jode.time. Is that the version you are using as well? Because I don't have the toEpochMilli method. :(

Comment: No, this is the Java 8 class `Instant`. But it has a similar method, `getMillis()`. See the [API documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Instant.html).

Comment: Or you can simply do - [`Instant.now().toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) ... :-)

Comment: @PrakashK But that will give you a `String`, not an `XMLGregorianCalendar`.